# Download an image if not found, then display it with async / promise

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have this bit of code, which is not working as I wish.

The aim is to check if a file is found. If found, then display it. If not found, then download it & display it.
I would like to use a promise resolving to the base64 image and use it in the src property.

The first time run is downloading the files, but doesn't display them.
On the subsequent runs, if I directly call  'readAsDataURL' I can see the pics, but if i call 'getphoto' there's nothing displayed even if the files are here.

I'm pretty sure the issue is in the returning type of the 'getphoto' function, but i can't wrap my head into making it work.

Here's the code :

```js
  async getPhoto(id: string) {
    this.file.checkFile(this.file.dataDirectory, id).then ( exist => {
      if (exist) {
        return this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.dataDirectory, id);
      } else {
        this.httpService.downloadMedia(id).subscribe(img => {
          this.createFile(id, img).then( () => {
            return this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.dataDirectory, id);
          });;
        });        
      }
    }, (error) => { 
      if (error['message'] == 'NOT_FOUND_ERR') {
        this.httpService.downloadMedia(id).subscribe(img => {
          this.createFile(id, img).then( () => {
            return this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.dataDirectory, id);
          });
        });        
      }
    })
  }

  async createFile(path: string, img: Blob) {
    this.file.checkFile(this.file.dataDirectory, path).then(exist => {
      if (!exist) {
        this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, path, img)
          .then(result => {
          })
      } else {
      }
    })
      .catch(errorCheck => {
        this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, path, img)
          .then(result => {
          })
      })
  }
```

html page side

```html
    <ion-img class="photo_card img-centered" [src]="photoB64 | async" (click)="openPhoto(photoB64)" > </ion-img>
```

ts controller side

```js
    this.photoB64 = this.fileService.getPhoto(''+this.nichoir.mediafiles[this.indexPhoto].id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses Observable. So you need to use `toPromise()` method to use `async` and `await` keywords correctly:

```
async getPhoto(id: string) {
    let file;
    try {
        
        let exist = await this.file.checkFile(this.file.dataDirectory, id).toPromise(); 
        console.log(`exist is: `, exist);    
        if (exist) {
            file = this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.dataDirectory, id).toPromise();
        }
        else {
            let img = await this.httpService.downloadMedia(id).toPromise();
            let result = await this.createFile(id, img).toPromise();
            file = await this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.dataDirectory, id).toPromise();;
        }
    }
    catch(ex) {
        let img = await this.httpService.downloadMedia(id).toPromise();
        let result = await this.createFile(id, img).toPromise();
        file = await this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.dataDirectory, id).toPromise();;
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is working better, but the pic still isn't displayed after download. It is visible if I change the page then come back though.
I had to remove the 'toPromise'  from these function that are already promises : readAsDataUrl & createFile (I edited the original post to put this code)

Comment: It's ok now , the createfile function was buggy.
Thanks !